# Only transfer updated portions of a file

Tags: scp

I do simulations on large supercomputers, and the files I produce are on the order of 5 GB to 1 TB.  But I frequently like to monitor the progress of the simulation using a visualization program on my laptop, so I'll transfer the log/data files while the simulation is still running.  When the simulation is over, I have to SCP the whole file again.  Is there a way to update just the new part that was added?

Comment: Consider using the Folding@Home or Seti@Home Projects to run/watch your simulation.

Comment: That won't work; my simulations require direct interprocessor communication (I'm using LAMMPS).

Comment: My direction was this, but I can't tell you how to do it.  Trade your file size in for smaller file sizes, and then chain the files together into work units.  Your current work unit is TOO BIG to be productive.  The normal software to use wd be git or tortiose, but even those monitor files, so thats out...

Comment: `sftp` is better to use but it will not solve your problem, you can transfer only updated and append it to file there. wt i suggest. transfer the updated data using a new file and do ssh and then `cat new_log >> old_log`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rsync` with the `--append` or `--append-verify` option. See the [rsync(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) man page for details.

Note: even without `--append` or `--append-verify`, `rsync` will be much more efficient than `scp` (but since your data are really big, you may need one of these options anyway).